# Angularjs + spring security members only section

Tags: java, angularjs, angularjs-module

I'm building a java webapp with a members only section using AngularJs. My question is in regards to AngularJs modules. Should I create two separate Angular modules for the members only and public portions of the app?

btw I'm new to angularjs.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a design descision that is up to you. For reference here is part of the AngularJS Documentation on [recommended module setup](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#recommended-setup)

> ### Recommended Setup
>
> While the example above is simple, it will not scale
>   to large applications. Instead we recommend that you break your
>   application to multiple modules like this:
>
> - A module for each feature
> - A module for each reusable component (especially directives and filters)
> - And an application level module which depends on the above modules and contains any initialization code.
>
> We've also [written a document](http://blog.angularjs.org/2014/02/an-angularjs-style-guide-and-best.html) on how we organize large apps at
>   Google.
>
> The above is a suggestion. Tailor it to your needs.

Your idea of splitting up the application into reusable parts makes sense with the "module for each filter" recommendation.